# Filter Datagridview rows using TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, filter

I have a binded datagridView and i want to filter it using a TextBox value.

I used this code:

```
private void ChercheStextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ((DataTable)dataGridView3.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("LibService like '%{0}%'", ChercheStextBox.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }
```

But this code doesn't filter the datagridView even i have used the same code

in another datagridView and it works perfectly. I don't know where is the

error in my code?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

i removed try catch and i got this error message:

> unable to cast object of type 'system.windows.forms.bindingsource' to type 'system.data.datatable'

How can i fix it??

Comment: Are you sure the column name (LibService) is correct?

Comment: Yes i'm sure it is correct

Comment: Have you bound the eventhandler to the right event? Put a breakpoint into that method and check the `RowFilter` property before leaving the method

Comment: Have you looked at the resulting filterstring? Care to post it?

Comment: i tried to put breakpoint but it doesn't give a value for Rowfilter

Comment: @TaW sorry i haven't understand

Comment: If you  really reach the line you posted you should be setting the RowFilter there. Put it in a string before assigning it..Do the breakpoint hit the line? Is ChercheStextBox_TextChanged hooked up in the TextBox's event properties?

Comment: I put RowFilter in string and i add a breakpoint there but the is no RowFilter value. i tried the same thing in the second datagridview and it gives me Rowfilter value

Comment: How can that be? of course you need to put some text in the filter textbox..What text do you enter there? Event then the _LibService like_ part should be there. Is the DataSource set?

Comment: Get rid of that empty try-catch. It's not helping you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The DataSource is a type of BindingSource not DataTable, so try this code:

```
private void ChercheStextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bd = (BindingSource)dataGridView3.DataSource;
        var dt = (DataTable)bd.DataSource;
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("LibService like '%{0}%'", ChercheStextBox.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));    
        dataGridView3.Refresh();


    }
```

Comment: Is this possible to count and get HeaderText and filter? actually, I don't want to specify any particular header value.

Comment: The first line didn't work, as the datagrid view casts to a DataTable. So it was sufficient to cast the datagridview datasource to the datatable and use it.

``var dt = (DataTable)dataGridView3.DataSource;

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use this Method :

```
 public void ChercheStextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //NASSIM LOUCHANI
          BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
          bs.DataSource = dataGridView3.DataSource;
          bs.Filter = string.Format("CONVERT(" + dataGridView3.Columns[1].DataPropertyName + ", System.String) like '%" + ChercheStextBox.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'");
          dataGridView3.DataSource = bs;

    }
```

All you need is change the Columns Number using a Combobox for Example ... just use your imagination .

Thank you .