# C# datagridview filtering based on all columns using textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

I want to filter datagridview table using all columns of the datagrid with textbox_change properties. I want create a code and i could not achieve please help me?

Briefly,
i create a dynamic table getting data randomly according  to selected parameters
and i want to filter this result without depending on any column name or number
i want to filter all columns.How can i do?

```css
 private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("allcolumns like '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Datagridview rows using TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433041/filter-datagridview-rows-using-textbox)

Comment: @haddow64 how to change the code dataGridView1.Columns[1] for searching all columns

Comment: A filter is just a `WHERE` clause. You should some research on that.

Comment: Use your current logic for the first column, then [OR additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18260960/3773066) using your same logic.